# Compile Kernel Module for different Kernel

Tags: linux, module, kernel

i am working with an embedded linux system, which i don't have kernel sources or headers too. Also i can not simply use another kernel.

However i got the kernel sources for another kernel-version and can compile that module for that kernel. But i can't load that module on my target system, because dmesg is saying 'version magic'

So, can i somehow make the module with a reference to another kernel? Where does the information about the kernel-version is read?

My target system has the kernel version '3.18.11-tegra', the kernel sources are 3.18.19..

Comment: If you don't have kernel sources, ask people who gave you the device to provide them. It's their legal obligation. (Chances are, they will point you to github and tell to download from there, which you probably can right now).

Answer (score 0):

Of course, your plan can only succeed if that module works unaltered with both kernel-versions, which is often the case; then you could plant `SUBLEVEL = 11` in the top level `Makefile` of your 3.18.19 kernel sources.

Answer (score 0):

Did the same thing some time ago on a different system
You will need download and compile the 3.18.11 kernel using their config. 
Go to https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/ and download 3.18.11
Unzip kernel into /usr/src/linux-3.18.11, cd into it then copy the current config

`make mrproper
zcat /proc/config.gz >.config
make oldconfig
make`

After you compile your kernel you need to create 2 symlinks under /usr/src

`ln -s linux-3.18.11 linux-3.18.11-tegra
ln -s linux-3.18.11 linux`

Now you should be able to compile your module with:

`make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) module`